# VS 2003: console application .net remoting

Tags: .net, remoting

Does any one know how to connect my c# console application to .net remoting server object. How to make changes to config file for console application to consume the .net remoting object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure: [.net Remoting: Building a Client Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6dc64f2%28VS.71%29.aspx)